# How to use Autofac / Castle DynamicProxy interceptors in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, autofac

I'm implementing an ASP.NET Core 6 service.

I'd like to implement an interceptor, chose Autofac based on earlier experience.

However, my interceptor is never executed.

Here's my DI configuration code in `Program.cs`:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

internal class Program
{
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.

    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    // Register Swagger
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    builder.Services.AddRequestHandlers();
    builder.Services.AddConfigurationRepository(builder.Configuration);

    // Register Autofac so that we can implement interceptors
    builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(autofacBuilder =>
    {
        autofacBuilder.RegisterType<ControllerExceptionHandlingInterceptor>();

        autofacBuilder.RegisterType<MyController>().SingleInstance()
            .EnableClassInterceptors()
            .InterceptedBy(typeof(ControllerExceptionHandlingInterceptor));
    });

    var app = builder.Build();

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
  }
}
```

The implementation of the interceptor:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using IInterceptor = Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor;
using IActionResult = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Wattle.Merchant.Configuration.Host
{
  public class ControllerExceptionHandlingInterceptor : IInterceptor
  {
    private readonly ILogger<ControllerExceptionHandlingInterceptor> _logger;

    public ControllerExceptionHandlingInterceptor(
        ILogger<ControllerExceptionHandlingInterceptor> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    #region Implement IInterceptor

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var methodInfo = invocation.MethodInvocationTarget;
        if (IsAsync(methodInfo))
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
            invocation.ReturnValue = InterceptAsync((dynamic)invocation.ReturnValue, invocation);
        }
        else
        {
            InterceptSync(invocation);
        }
    }

    private async Task<TResult> InterceptAsync<TResult>(Task<TResult> task, IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (TResult)HandleException(invocation, ex);
        }
    }

    private void InterceptSync(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            invocation.ReturnValue = HandleException(invocation, ex);
        }
    }

    #endregion Implement IInterceptor

    private IActionResult HandleException(IInvocation invocation, Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, $"{invocation.Method.Name} failed.");

        if (ex.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ValidationException)))
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, ex.Message);

        if (ex.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(NotFoundException)))
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, ex.Message);

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }

    public static bool IsAsync(MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (method.ReturnType == typeof(Task))
            return true;

        if (method.ReturnType.IsGenericType && method.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    private static ObjectResult StatusCode(
        [ActionResultStatusCode] int statusCode,
        [ActionResultObjectValue] object? value)
    {
        return new ObjectResult(value)
        {
            StatusCode = statusCode
        };
    }
  }
}
```

Placing a breakpoint within the `Intercept()` method is never hit, `_logger.LogError()` is never called.

I assume there's something wrong with my Autofac service registration code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend using global exception filters instead of manual interception for the intended behavior you want there. Exception filters were designed for this purpose while interceptors might look "strange" to people looking at your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to intercept at the controller level, you need to make sure that ASPNET Core is *resolving* the controllers from the container. This is actually not done by default: instead, ASPNET Core will create the controllers and resolve only its dependencies via the container (using something like `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstace` behind the scenes).

To make it so that your controllers are registered in the container and picked up as registered services by ASPNET Core, you actually need to add a special call after `AddControllers`, like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();
```

Now your controllers are discovered and automatically added as registrations on the container. Anything you do on top of them (be it decorators, interceptors, etc) should now work as expected.

PS: I tend to always add `AddControllersAsServices()` on my APIs as a best practice to allow for the automatic container checking to inspect controller classes as well during development (to detect missing registrations). Without controllers registered, the container is completely unaware of them and will not perform the standard check at that level as well.

Comment: Awesome!Descriptive, to the point, just what I needed, problem solved!
Thank you!